# MKMapViewDelegate Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapviewdelegate

i have a very weird problem with a MKMapViewDelegate when i implement this method give me an error that i do not understand

The error only disappear when i delete the whole function,

i tried to make a empty function returning nil but give me the same error.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

  if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation.classForCoder()) {
        return nil
    }
    let AnnotationIdentifier:NSString = "AnnotationIdentifier"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(AnnotationIdentifier)

    if annotationView != nil {
        return annotationView
    }else {
        var annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: AnnotationIdentifier)

        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "btn_fav.png")


        return annotationView

    }


}
```

The error:
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

```
CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/Fortis/Proyectos/IOS Apps/Abilia/Abilia iOS/Abilia/Abilia/Vistas/Proyecto/MapaViewController.swift
    cd /Users/Fortis/Proyectos/IOS Apps/Abilia/Abilia iOS/Abilia
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c "/Users/Fortis/Proyectos/IOS Apps/Abilia/Abilia iOS/Abilia/Abilia/Classes/NetClass/Downloader.swift" -primary-file "/Users/Fortis/Proyectos/IOS Apps/Abilia/Abilia iOS/Abilia/Abilia/Vistas/Proyecto/MapaViewController.swift" "/Users/Fortis/Proyectos/IOS Apps/Abilia/Abilia iOS/Abilia/Abilia/Vistas/Widget/ToggleView.swift" .
```

.
.
.

```
0  swift                    0x00000001019df028 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40
1  swift                    0x00000001019df514 SignalHandler(int) + 452
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff9a2dc5aa _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 1708276336
4  swift                    0x0000000100fe90ea swift::ClangImporter::Implementation::loadAllMembers(swift::Decl const*, unsigned long long, bool*) + 3130
5  swift                    0x0000000101da2834 swift::IterableDeclContext::loadAllMembers() const + 100
6  swift                    0x0000000101d995dc swift::NominalTypeDecl::getMembers(bool) const + 28
7  swift                    0x0000000101dc029f swift::NominalTypeDecl::lookupDirect(swift::DeclName) + 79
8  swift                    0x0000000101dbe96a swift::DeclContext::lookupQualified(swift::Type, swift::DeclName, unsigned int, swift::LazyResolver*, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::ValueDecl*>&) const + 3146
9  swift                    0x0000000100fe5941 (anonymous namespace)::SwiftDeclConverter::VisitObjCPropertyDecl(clang::ObjCPropertyDecl const*, swift::DeclContext*) + 161
10 swift                    0x0000000100fe0d0d clang::declvisitor::Base<clang::declvisitor::make_const_ptr, (anonymous namespace)::SwiftDeclConverter, swift::Decl*>::Visit(clang::Decl const*) + 3117
11 swift                    0x0000000100fe005b swift::ClangImporter::Implementation::importDeclImpl(clang::NamedDecl const*, bool&, bool&) + 331
12 swift                    0x0000000100fe4912 swift::ClangImporter::Implementation::importDeclAndCacheImpl(clang::NamedDecl const*, bool) + 226
13 swift                    0x0000000100fe879e swift::ClangImporter::Implementation::loadAllMembers(swift::Decl const*, unsigned long long, bool*) + 750
14 swift                    0x0000000101da2834 swift::IterableDeclContext::loadAllMembers() const + 100
15 swift                    0x0000000101d99a95 swift::ExtensionDecl::getMembers(bool) const + 21
16 swift                    0x0000000101dc027d swift::NominalTypeDecl::lookupDirect(swift::DeclName) + 45
17 swift                    0x0000000101dbe96a swift::DeclContext::lookupQualified(swift::Type, swift::DeclName, unsigned int, swift::LazyResolver*, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::ValueDecl*>&) const + 3146
18 swift                    0x0000000101cc6288 swift::TypeChecker::lookupMember(swift::Type, swift::DeclName, swift::DeclContext*, bool) + 200
19 swift                    0x0000000101c34e2c swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::lookupMember(swift::Type, swift::DeclName) + 220
20 swift                    0x0000000101c6b32d swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::simplifyMemberConstraint(swift::constraints::Constraint const&) + 2173
21 swift                    0x0000000101c6dc88 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::simplifyConstraint(swift::constraints::Constraint const&) + 216
22 swift                    0x0000000101c354bc swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::addConstraint(swift::constraints::Constraint*, bool, bool) + 28
23 swift                    0x0000000101c5a8a5 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::ConstraintGenerator, swift::Type, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Expr*) + 9317
24 swift                    0x0000000101c5c502 (anonymous namespace)::ConstraintWalker::walkToExprPost(swift::Expr*) + 162
25 swift                    0x0000000101d6627f (anonymous namespace)::Traversal::visit(swift::Expr*) + 6431
26 swift                    0x0000000101d62765 swift::Expr::walk(swift::ASTWalker&) + 53
27 swift                    0x0000000101c583b0 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::generateConstraints(swift::Expr*) + 96
28 swift                    0x0000000101c90ab6 swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::Type, bool, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*) + 518
29 swift                    0x0000000101cd73e3 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtChecker, void, swift::Stmt*, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 291
30 swift                    0x0000000101cd64c3 swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckFunctionBodyUntil(swift::FuncDecl*, swift::SourceLoc) + 371
31 swift                    0x0000000101cd6b8f swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckAbstractFunctionBody(swift::AbstractFunctionDecl*) + 95
32 swift                    0x0000000101c86b65 typeCheckFunctionsAndExternalDecls(swift::TypeChecker&) + 421
33 swift                    0x0000000101c87476 swift::performTypeChecking(swift::SourceFile&, swift::TopLevelContext&, unsigned int) + 1734
34 swift                    0x0000000100fc07dd swift::CompilerInstance::performSema() + 2253
35 swift                    0x0000000100d54831 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 1953
36 swift                    0x0000000100d5294d main + 1677
37 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff960e05fd start + 1
38 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000061 start + 1777465957
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/Fortis/Proyectos/IOS Apps/Abilia/Abilia iOS/Abilia/Abilia/Classes/NetClass/Downloader.swift -primary-file /Users/Fortis/Proyectos/IOS Apps/Abilia/Abilia iOS/Abilia/Abilia/Vistas/Proyecto/MapaViewController.swift /Users/Fortis/Proyectos/IOS Apps/Abilia/Abilia iOS/Abilia/Abilia/Vistas/Widget/ToggleView.swift /Users/Fortis/Proyectos/IOS Apps/Abilia/Abilia iOS/Abilia/Abilia/Classes/Entities/Mapa.swift /Users/Fortis/Proyectos/IOS Apps/Abilia/Abilia iOS/Abilia/Abilia/Classes/Entities/Edificio__c.swift .
```

.
.
.
.
    1.  While type-checking 'loadMapa' at /Users/Fortis/Proyectos/IOS Apps/Abilia/Abilia iOS/Abilia/Abilia/Vistas/Proyecto/MapaViewController.swift:56:5
    2.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/Fortis/Proyectos/IOS Apps/Abilia/Abilia iOS/Abilia/Abilia/Vistas/Proyecto/MapaViewController.swift:57:9 - line:57:29] RangeText="mapaView.delegate = s"

```
func loadMapa () {
        mapaView.delegate = self
        var theCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0)
        if let coordenadasU = coordenadas {
            let coordArray:[NSString] = coordenadasU.componentsSeparatedByString(",") as [NSString]
            if coordArray.count > 1 {
                let lat: CLLocationDegrees = coordArray[0].doubleValue;
                let long: CLLocationDegrees = coordArray[1].doubleValue;
                theCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)


            }

        }

        pointAnnotation.coordinate = theCoord;
        mapaView.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)

        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: theCoord, span: span)

        mapaView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        mapaLoaded = true;

    }
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue in Xcode 6.0.1 GM. Same stack trace, and it's happening when I'm assigning the `delegate` property of the `MKMapView`.

Comment: Also happens in Xcode 6.1 GM 2.

Comment: Well, i still have not a clue, Is there a other solution? 
Regards

Comment: I ended up writing wrapper methods in Objective-C, and calling them from Swift. For example, `+ (void)removeAllAnnotations:(MKMapView *)map;`, then call it from Swift: `MapWorkarounds.removeAllAnnotations(map: mapView)` This both compiles and runs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of Swift's many bugs where the compiler suddenly crashes because of specific code in your app it cannot handle.

You have to isolate the problematic part (e.g. by commenting out parts of the screen) and once it compiles again find a workaround to use different code.

How does your method `loadMapa` look like? It's the cause the compiler mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i just add the code of roadmap. Ok, i suppose that is a bug because a was working with xcode beta7 and worked when update to the last version it happened.

Comment: Wish I'd stuck with Objective-C now. It has just been hassle from the off.

Comment: @AdamWaite Yeah it takes a while (and latest Xcode 6.1) to get used to it and regain productivity again.

Comment: Has 6.1 fixed things?

Comment: @AdamWaite at least the situation was improved. Less crashes.

Comment: The same thing has just happened to me with MKMapViewDelegate, wasn't there in 6.0.1

Comment: At the end it was a bug i think, in the new release works ok.

Comment: I have Xcode 6.1 and it was giving me this error and I insisted with command+b and sunddenly it compiled successfuly

Answer (score 2):

I had same error when subclassing UIButton and overriding selected property like this:

```
class ActionButton: UIButton {

    override var selected: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            updateBackgroundColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Solution was to remove ' = true' from the override statement:

```
class ActionButton: UIButton {

    override var selected: Bool {
        didSet {
            updateBackgroundColor()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just guessing but I would double-check if you implemented your delegate method exactly right way... With all exclamation marks correctly given... '!' at the end of  MKAnnotationView! seems to be a bit suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

I've searched why The error: "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11" is causing problems in my app... My app is Parse dependent. I found out that Parse made changes to method:

> ```
>         query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
> ```

to

> ```
>         query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects : [**PFObject**]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
> ```

I've changed it all, and now it works. Hope this will help someone using Parse. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not really a specific answer, but I wanted to add another possible cause of this bug (since it's still quite common).

My program had code like so:

```
if (myArray.count > 0) && (.Foo != myArray.last) {
    // Do something
}
```

In my case `.Foo` belonged to an enum for which I'd implemented `Equatable`, however, for some reason the Swift compiler didn't highlight my comparison to `myArray.last` as an error (non-optional compared to optional) and produced a segmentation fault.

In my case the fix was simply to use `myArray.last!` since the `myArray.count > 0` ensures this will always succeed (must be at least one element).

As usual, once you know what the bug is, be sure to pass it on to `bug report.apple.com`!